# Android - как удалить приложение из Play Market?

Tags: android, google-play

Недавно опубликовал своё приложение в Play Markete. Понял, что допустил ошибку. Теперь его оттуда нужно удалить. Как?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Перейти на https://play.google.com/apps/publish
- Раздел «приложение».
- Далее, «файлы apk».
- Переключится в расширенный режим.
- Деактивировать.

Comment: Не работает. Раньше было всё понятно, а теперь что-то не то... После деактивации сохранить изменения нельзя.

Comment: Выдает что нельзя! Нужно, мол, что бы хоть одна версия была активна...